# Cannot scroll the screen when mouse hovers over HtmlElementView

Tags: flutter, iframe, flutter-web

I'm trying to put ads on my website using iFrame and HtmlElementView component in Flutter Web. The whole ad code is inside an external file. The problem is when I hover mouse over the ad element and try to scroll up or down it doesn't work, the ad intercepts an action. I tried to use https://pub.dev/packages/pointer_interceptor but for this issue it doesn't work.

Code of method displaying single ad:

```
      double width, double height, String htmlPageName, String viewType) {
    // ignore: undefined_prefixed_name
    ui.platformViewRegistry.registerViewFactory(
        viewType,
        (int viewID) => IFrameElement()
          ..src = htmlPageName
          ..style.border = 'none');

    return PointerInterceptor(
      child: Container(
        height: height,
        width: width,
        child: HtmlElementView(
          viewType: viewType,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

And an example of its usage

```
buildContent() => Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(32),
        child: Container(
          child: PointerInterceptor(
            child: SingleChildScrollView(
              primary: false,
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  buildSomething(),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 16,
                  ),
                  buildSomething(),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 16,
                  ),
                  AdsManager.displayHtmlBannerFromExternalFile(320, 300,
                      "banner_ads_300_250.html", "banner300x250"),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 4,
                  ),
                  buildSomething(),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      );
```

There's a html code for the ad(banner_ads_300_250.html)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div id="adm-container-5494"></div>
<script data-cfasync="false" async type="text/javascript" src="//examplead.com/app/display/items.php?5494&2322&300&250&4&0&0"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

What do I do wrong? Looking forward to your answers.

Answer (score 0):

You need put the pointer intercepter on a transparent widget you put on top of the html:

```
Stack(
                    children: [
                      SizedBox(
                        width: _iFrameWidth,
                        height: _iFrameHeight + 30,
                        child: _iframeWidget,
                      ),
                      PointerInterceptor(
                        intercepting: _isInterceptingPointers,
                        debug: true,
                        child: Material(
                          color: Colors.transparent,
                          child: SizedBox(
                            width: _iFrameWidth,
                            height: _iFrameHeight - 10,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
```